# SQL unpredictable failure

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net

I wrote an SQL stored procedure, that's called trough an `SqlDataSource` element (in a ASP.NET / C# web application).
To be more precise the procedure is called from within a trigger of `tableA` bound on the `AFTER INSERT` event:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `create_checklist`(IN _id_A INT(10))
BEGIN
    DECLARE _mode CHAR(4);
    DECLARE _id_default INT(10);

    SELECT 
        mode
    FROM
        tableA
    WHERE
        id = _id_A INTO _mode;

   SELECT
        id
    FROM
        tab_doc_type
    WHERE
        def_value = 1 INTO _id_default;

   # LOCK TABLES TableA WRITE;
   # START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO checklist 
         (id_type, id_A, priority)
         SELECT id_doc_type, _id_A, priority
         FROM tab_checklist 
         WHERE A_mode = _mode;

    UPDATE
        checklist
    SET
        not_needed = 1
    WHERE
        (id_A = _id_A ) AND (id_type = _id_default);

    # COMMIT;
    # UNLOCK TABLES;
END

CREATE TRIGGER `tableA_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON `tableA` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL create_checklist(NEW.id);

    IF NEW.mode = 'X' OR NEW.mode = 'Y' THEN
        CALL create_booking(NEW.id);
    END IF;
END
```

that should create the `checklist` entries for an element of the `tableA` and then update one of the checlist entries with a flag (`not_needed` ) with a predefined value.

My SQL backend is a MySQL server.

This works in most of the cases but users reports that 'sometime' the procedure fails without errors being shown, the `checklist` is not filled up so I'm assuming that INSERT command is not executed.

I'm not able to reproduce this behaviour.

I've been notified from a user the value of an `_id_A` on which the procedure failed and triggering it 'manually' from the **MySQL SQL Editor** worked withtout problems.

I tried to enclose lines of codes 'writing' data in table with `LOCK TABLES .. UNLOCK TABLES` and/or `START TRANSACTION ... COMMIT` without success. In both cases it seems that stored procedure cannot use such commands.

Anyone here is able to locate a possible failure reason?
There's a way to fix this?

In short there's a way to call the stored procedure from within the trigger and avoid race condition so the `checklist` table is correctly populated every time?

Comment: Most likely cause:  race condition with two queries running the sp at the same time, so something "unexpected" happens between the insert and update.  You might want to lock the table that is being modified.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  `LOCK TABLES` cannot be used inside stored procedures.

Comment: **Start Transaction** perhaps.

Comment: @FDavidov I already tried this... I'm going to wait for a confirmation. Thnx for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: @FDavidov it doesn't work either ... COMMIT (implicit or explicit) cannot be issued inside stored procedure.

Comment: @weirdgyn, I think you are wrong about invoking COMMIT within a stored procedure (I have a full project implemented and I definitely do use COMMIT!!!). I do recall that MySQL has limitations for FUNCTIONS but... If you cannot invoke COMMIT within a stored procedure, where can you do it?

Comment: @FDavidov I was just wondering the same ... by the fact I got this error that say "you cannot use explicit or implicit COMMIT inside a stored procedure" this's the message inside an exception that's thrown by the ASP.NET app that's running the procedure itself.
To be correct the procedure is called not by the asp.net page itself but is called by a trigger bound to the after insert event of `tableA`...

Comment: Ok ok... Check if COMMIT can be invoked from a TRIGGER. I guess the answer will be NO. See? To the best of my recollection, you CAN commit from a stored procedure that is invoked as part of a normal process (say, from command line). When the same procedure is called from within a trigger, it is a completely different story.